# Can Tomcat and apache do use async I/O using NIO?

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, asynchronous, nio

The biggest selling point of async frameworks such as node.js has been to claim that traditional servers such as Tomcat and Apache can't do single-threaded non-blocking I/O to scale to millions of connections. However I see that Java does support non-blocking async I/O through its NIO API. Why not the servers replace existing architecture to use NIO and get to the same levels of scalability?

Comment: Apache HTTPD isn't written in Java so it can't use NIO, but it can certainly use async I/O, and I'm not aware of any major complaints about its performance. Tomcat is, and can. If such a claim is made it is nonsense.

Comment: @EJP, Thanks! I missed the Apache HTTPD part. And yes, the only reason why node.js is getting popular, as far as I see, is its scalability over Tomcat+Apache for web requests.